# How to write an image to pdf using its dataURL?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, data-url

I have downloaded jsPDF to write pdf files from dataURLs. according to their documentation jsPDF only writes jpeg images to pdf, so I tried to do this

```
var img_dataurljpg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

but when I reconstruct the dataURL it's not that image, it's a whole black image. Also when I pass image_dataurljpg to addImage function of jsPDF

```
function onSavePDF(url){
    var imgData = url;
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 40, 180, 180);
    doc.save('slide no ' + n+'.pdf');
}
```

I recieve

```
Uncaught Error: getJpegSize could not find the size of the image jspdf.plugin.addimage.js:56
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Could this be an issue with the same origin policy -- do you get an exception somewhere? Do you draw images from other hosts in your canvas?